# Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module in fastify project

Tags: node.js, fastify, fastify-swagger

Trying to import `fastify-openapi-glue` in my fastify project but getting error `ERR_REQUIRE_ESM` and I'm using typescript in the application.

Code looks like below

> routes.ts file

```
/* eslint-disable node/no-unsupported-features/es-syntax */
import { FastifyInstance } from 'fastify';
// import openapiGlue from 'fastify-openapi-glue';
// const openapiGlue = await import("fastify-openapi-glue");

import { Service } from '../controllers/service';

async function loadOpenapiGlue() {
  const openapiGlueModule = await import('fastify-openapi-glue');
  return openapiGlueModule.default;
}

const options = {
  specification: './openapi.yaml',
  service: new Service()
};

export default async (app: FastifyInstance): Promise<void> => {
  const openapiGlue = await loadOpenapiGlue();
  app.register(openapiGlue, options);
};
```

> tsconfig.json file

```
{
  "ts-node": {
    "require": ["tsconfig-paths/register"]
  },
  "compilerOptions": {
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "lib": ["ES2020"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "rootDirs": ["src"],
    "outDir": "dist",
    "plugins": [],
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "target": "ES2020",
    "types": ["node", "jest"],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"]
}
```

**Note:**
After updating the module under tsconfig.json as mentioned in other stackoverflow answer as `"module": "ES2022"`, I'm getting error like `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

Comment: You can't use `"module": "commonjs",` if you have installed a pure ESM package

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon After updating it as `"module": "ES2022"`, I'm getting error like `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

Comment: You need to update your package.json as well